# SQL Server 2008 DB - Autogrowth failure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

SQL Server 2008 R2 database is not able to grow beyond the initial size even though auto-growth option is set to increase database size by 500MB. I tried to increase the size manully but it failed with below error:

```
Modify file encountered operating system error 665 
(the requested operation cannot be completed due to file system limitation) 
while attempting to expand the physical file (Microsoft SQL Server, Error 5149)
```

I have lot of free space on the drive, but not sure why this error is occurring.

Comment: Does the Autogrowth have a maximum file size set?

Comment: Also check for Windows disk quotas.

Answer (score 0):

I remember reading about something similar a while back and the error was related to the NTFS file system being too fragmented, making it impossible to grow files further as the attribute list that stores information about the file allocations would reach its limit. The work around might be to defragment the volume containing the files.

[This article from Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;967351) could be relevant.